# BufferReader program prints the input file (text file) in reverse order line by line, but it also prints the words in reverse order

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://Users/ALAN/Desktop/mary.txt"));
        String lines = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (lines != null) {
            if (lines != null) {
                buffer.add("\n");
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String[] splitStr = lines.split(" ");
                for (int i = splitStr.length; i > 0; i--) {
                    str.append(splitStr[i - 1]).append(" ");
                }
                buffer.add(str.toString());
            }
            lines = br.readLine();
        }
        for(int i = buffer.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(buffer.get(i));
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make my program print out my text file in reverse line by line, but not have it reverse the words.

For example, I have an output:

```
reply. did teacher the 23 
know." you lamb, the loves Mary "Why, 22 
21 
cry. children eager the 20
```

Instead of

```
23 the teacher did reply.
22 "Why, Mary loves the lamb, you know."
21
20 the eager children cry.
```

Comment: Well you have code in there specifically to reverse the lines - look at the block with the `for` statement of `for (int i = splitStr.length; i > 0; i--) `. Why do you have that code if you *don't* want to reverse the words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This counts from `splitStr.length` to 1 in descending order:

```
for (int i = splitStr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    str.append(splitStr[i - 1]).append(" ");
}
```

So you're iterating the `splitStr` array in reverse order.

The code below will iterate in crescent (non-reverse) order, counting from 0 to less than `splitStr.length`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    str.append(splitStr[i]).append(" ");
}
```

Or you can simply write:

```
for (String element : splitStr) {
    str.append(element).append(" ");
}
```

The same applies to the loop iterating `buffer`:

```
for (int i = buffer.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(buffer.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
public class BufferReader2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("README.txt"));

        String lines = br.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (lines != null) {


            if(lines != null)
            {
                buffer.add(lines);
                buffer.add("\n");
            }
                        lines=br.readLine();

        }

        for(int i = buffer.size()-1; i>0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(buffer.get(i));
        }

        br.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```